# Hive: Metastore doesn't gets updated once table is renamed and altered

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have an external table name MIAC and I renamed it to MIAC_BKUP. Also, I renamed the location of external table from MIAC to MIAC_bkup using Alter statement.

Now I create a new external table with name MIAC again to populate new values but I see MIAC_BKUP is also getting updated with new values only and no bckup values.

I suspect metastore not getting updated.  I ran MSCK repair but no go.

## both are partitioned tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is 3 thing you have change in your process.

1. Rename table from MIAC to MIAC_bkup (you did that)
2. Rename table location `hdfs:///<some-lcoation>/MIAC` to `hdfs:///<some-lcoation>/MIAC_bkup` (which you also did)
3. **Letting the table know about your new location with below query.**

```
ALTER TABLE MIAC_bkup SET LOCATION "hdfs:///<some-lcoation>/MIAC_bkup"
```

So when you added data into new MIAC, both backup and new tables are pointing to `hdfs:///<some-lcoation>/MIAC`. This is the reason you were seeing data in the backup table added via new table.

> Untill here everything should work for you. *Even you don’t have to do msck repair.*
>
> I believe you don’t have partition, because in that case your issue would be different.
>   **But if the table has partition please follow these additional steps.**

In the metadata, hive also stores partition location.
So your existing partition metadata doesn’t know about the location change.
You need to refresh the partition metadata also.

`MSCK REPAIR` alone wouldn’t do this job. You have to 1st drop all partition info from metadata then do the MSCK to sync older partition which are in backup location.

```
-- drop all partiotion
ALTER TABLE MIAC_bkup DROP PARTITION(partition_name <> ''); --refer this to understand 

-- repair table
MSCK REPAIR TABLE MIAC_bkup;
```

> NB: MSCK repair doesn’t delete partition, it only adds or checks inconsistency

Comment: Your answer makes sense. And we are basically doing the same thing. I will just have a check and accept your answer. 

Comment: Yeah. If you are dropping the table, all metadata will be dropped along with partition metadata. And when you re-create the table, initially it doesn’t have any partition info. After you do MSCK it will look into the location specified in table def and sync it add partition.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. It also works when we simply drop the table and re- create it again.